# How to reduce the minimum screen timeout?

Tags: root-access, stock-android, screen-timeout

I was trying to programmatically set the screen timeout to 5 seconds, because the minimum value provided by my Android OS is 10 seconds, which is more than enough for me. But I was out of luck!
Is there any way to reduce the minimum screen timeout in Android by editing the build.prop file? If yes, then how?

Comment: Why do you want to restrict the solution to build.prop only?

Comment: No, its not like that I want to restrict the solution to build.prop only. I know that it's not possible to do things like this without root and tweaking features is done through the build.prop file. So, that's why I asked this.

Comment: why are you trying to reduce it, just use the power button to off/on. if you tried to reduce by build.prop, it will be a huge work to do with associated files with it.

Comment: It is because, sometimes we forget to turn off the screen. But still, I think you are right, I need to have the habit of turning off the screen manually.